# Aurdino EMG sensors and servos?

Tags: programming, sketch, wires

I'm new here and to the aurdino.

I'm building a 3D printed robotic arm controlled by a EMG sensor. I purchased a V3 EMG board and leads on Aliexpress. Here's a list of the things I've purchase for this project

- Arduino Uno
- EMG sensor
- 2 MG996R servos 7.2 max voltage I know not to power these through the
  board.
- X4 AA battery pack with male barrel input lead to power the arduino.
  Wiring, header pins and cables.

I don't have any breadboards BTW.

The functionality is basic, servos on pulleys and strings, I'm looking for one servo to control the open close hand function, and the other is to open and close the index and thumb for a pinch function to pick up smaller objects.

I need to know the following,

Option to power servo, EMG sensor and arduino from single power source or two batteries and how to wire these a simple picture or schematic would be great.

What code can I quickly copy and paste to perform the functions I mentioned.

I do have some very basic DC electronic experience.

I just don't want to damage my components by just experimenting as it takes weeks to replace them otherwise.  Thanks.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: "What code can I quickly copy and paste to preform the functions I mentioned." - Most likely you won't find a code online, that does exactly, what you want (and we are not a googling machine to search for them). So you will most likely need to write that code yourself. Yes, that will take a while, but you can look at tutorials for each individual part of the project, understand them, and then use that code and understanding for your project. When you have each individual part working, you can put all these things together in one code.

Comment: On [Arduino Projecthub](https://create.arduino.cc/projecthub) you can find a lot of tutorials about robotic arms. I don't know what EMG sensor you own, but [here](https://www.seeedstudio.com/blog/2019/12/27/what-is-emg-sensor-myoware-and-how-to-use-with-arduino/) is an tutorial.

Comment: Your question is like asking for source code and schematic for a prosthetic arm that could be in a million dollar commercial project. I guess there are a few people sharing their work on the internet, but I doubt there is one that you can just, here I quote your words, "quickly copy and paste to perform the functions I mentioned"